# asp.net GridView IF empty show message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got a grid view. I want it to say "you have nothing to show" if there are no details.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound


    If GridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Lblemptygridview.Text = "you do no details to show"

    Elseif e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow then
        Dim datakey As String = GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString()

    End If


End Sub
```

However; it seems to be working backwards and showing the message when there is data to display in the gird view and continues to be a blank page when there is not data to display in the grid view.

I've tried a variety of combinations with the below IF statement below but no success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead, use the [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx):

```
 <emptydatatemplate>
        No Data Found.  
    </emptydatatemplate>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is more of an addendum to Icarus's answer, adding a bit of context as to why your solution does not work.  (For educational purposes).

RowDataBound is called when a Row is bound to the gridview.  This basically means that this is called for every row in the grid view.

Now, the reason why your solution doesn't work, is that if your GridView simply has nothing in it, RowDataBound will *not* be called.

The reason why you're getting 'No Data Found' when you DO have data, is because the first time the if statement runs when loading a GridView, the GridView (at the time of execution) has no Rows, which results in your if statement being true.

Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion..
Instead of showing "you have nothing to show" in a gridview which looks outdated, why don't you make it fancy??
You can do

```
        Dim dt As DataTable = getDatatable()

        If Not dt Is Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            GridView1.datasource = dt
            GridView1.databind()
            div.style.add("display", "none")
        Else
            GridView1.visible = False
            'Add some fancy style here to show no record
            div.style.add("display", "block")
        End If
```

thanks

Comment: Sometimes it's good to explicitly tell the user that no results were found; it depends on the situation.