# print report in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

hello i have created a purchase report in which i have used the grid but in case when the no of rows are less ie in case of one or two rows i have to add deafult row without binding the datacolumns so that the grid looks better and also when i print report i dont want to show this print button and url 
of my window[image]

and i have to display some thing like this

[image]

this is my aspx code

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td class="style1">
            <div class="cmpnylogo">
            <!--<img id="imglogo" runat="server"/>-->
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style69">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                <div>

                                    <table style="width:100%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style61">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Office"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbloffice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style61">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="Works"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblworks" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style61">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblphone" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="style61">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblmail" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="style58" colspan="2">
                                <hr />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
            </div>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="style1">
                <div class="dvtitle">
                <div class="title">Purchase Order</div>

                </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="style1">
                <table style="width:100%;border-left-style:none;border-right-style:none;" border="1px">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style64" valign="top">
                            <table style="width:100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style70">
                                        <div class="dvitems">
                                            Kind attn:-
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                  <asp:Label ID="lblattn" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style70">
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style70">
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblpartyadd" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style63" valign="top">
                            <table style="width:117%; height: 126px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style68">
                           <div class="dvpo">Consignee
                           </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                           <asp:Label ID="lblconsignee" runat="server"> 
                           </asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style68">
                                            <div>
                                                Name</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblconname" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style68">
                                            <div>
                                                Address</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblconadd" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style68">
                                            <div>
                                                City</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblconcity" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style68">
                                            <div>
                                                TINNO.</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblcontinno" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style68">
                                            <div>
                                                ECC NO</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                          <asp:Label ID="lblconeccno" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        <td valign="top" align="left">

                            <table style="width:100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style67">
                                        <div class="dvpo">
                                            PoNo:</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblpono" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style67">
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="style67">
                                        <div class="dvpo">
                                            Date:</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
            <div class="dvright">

            </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">

                                    <div class="dvitems">Dear Sir/Mam,</div>
                                    </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">

            <div class="dvinstruction">
 We are Pleased to order the under mentioned item kindly make the arrangements for the dispatch of same

             </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">



            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
             <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
  <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;min-height:500px;">                                             
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" width:auto Height:auto AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" style="min-width:700px"
  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

                         <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itdsrno" HeaderText="Srno" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itemname" HeaderText="Item" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itdlength" HeaderText="Gsm" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltotalquan" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                         </FooterTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblquantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itdquan")
```

%>'>

String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"itdRate")) %>' >

```
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbltxttotal" runat="server"  />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text='<%#
```

String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"itdAmou")) %>' >

```
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itdrema" HeaderText="Remark" />
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
</div>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and cs code is

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int compcode=0;
        c.GetConection();
        if(Session["compcode"]!=null)
        {
        compcode=Convert.ToInt32(Session["compcode"]);
        DataTable dtcomp = new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmdcom = new SqlCommand("sp_Getcompanyinfobycode",c.con);
        cmdcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdcom.Connection = c.con;
        cmdcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compcode", compcode);
        da.SelectCommand = cmdcom;
        da.Fill(dtcomp);
        if (dtcomp.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dtcomp.Rows[0]["compadd1"] != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtcomp.Rows[0]["compadd1"].ToString()))
                {

                    lbloffice.Text= dtcomp.Rows[0]["compadd1"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lbloffice.Text = "";
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtcomp.Rows[0]["compphor"].ToString()))
                {

                    lblphone.Text = dtcomp.Rows[0]["compphor"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblphone.Text = "";
                }

            }
        }




        }



        System.Data.DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select convert(int,itdquan) as itdquan,convert(int,itdlength) as itdlength, * from tmpMateIn", c.con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            //if (dt.Rows.Count < 5)
            //{
            //    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "" });

            //}
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;

            GridView1.DataBind();



        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {


            if (dt.Rows[0]["mstdate"] != null)
            {
                lbldeliverydt.Text = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt.Rows[0]["mstdate"]);
            }
            else
            {
                lbldeliverydt.Text = "";
            }
            if ((dt.Rows[0]["mstdeliDes"])!=null)
            {
                lblcity.Text = dt.Rows[0]["mstdeliDes"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblcity.Text = "";
            }
            if ((dt.Rows[0]["mstfrghtper"] != null))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0]["mstfrghtper"].ToString()))
                {
                    decimal mstfrght = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["mstfrghtper"].ToString());
                    lbldiscbill.Text = String.Format("{0:f2}", mstfrght);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbldiscbill.Text = "";
            }
            if ((dt.Rows[0]["msttaxper"] != null))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0]["msttaxper"].ToString()))
                {
                    decimal msttaxper = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["msttaxper"].ToString());

                    lbltax.Text = String.Format("{0:f2}", msttaxper);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbltax.Text = "";
            }
            if ((dt.Rows[0]["mstpayDes"] != null))
            {
                lblpterm.Text = dt.Rows[0]["mstpayDes"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblpterm.Text = "";
            }
            if ((dt.Rows[0]["itdrefq"] != null))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0]["itdrefq"].ToString()))
                {
                    decimal itdrefq = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["itdrefq"].ToString());
                    lblvattinno.Text = String.Format("{0:f2}", itdrefq);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblvattinno.Text = "";
            }

            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dtmtdetail = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Getordemstdetailbycode", c.con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mstcode", dt.Rows[0]["mstcode"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compcode", dt.Rows[0]["compcode"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msttype", dt.Rows[0]["msttype"]);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dtmtdetail);
            if (dtmtdetail.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if ((dtmtdetail.Rows[0]["mstindno"] != null))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtmtdetail.Rows[0]["mstindno"].ToString()))
                    {
                        decimal mstindno = Convert.ToDecimal(dtmtdetail.Rows[0]["mstindno"].ToString());
                        lblcsttinno.Text = string.Format("{0:f2}", mstindno);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblcsttinno.Text = "";
                }
                if ((dtmtdetail.Rows[0]["mstsection"] != null))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtmtdetail.Rows[0]["mstsection"].ToString()))
                    {
                        lbleccno.Text = string.Format("{0:f2}", dtmtdetail.Rows[0]["mstsection"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lbleccno.Text = "";
                }





            }

            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dtpartyinfo = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp_GetAccountinfo", c.con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acctname", dt.Rows[0]["acctname"]);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
            da.Fill(dtpartyinfo);
            if (dtpartyinfo.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                if (dt.Rows[0]["acctaddr"] != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtpartyinfo.Rows[0]["acctaddr"].ToString()))
                    {

                        lblpartyadd.Text = dtpartyinfo.Rows[0]["acctaddr"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblpartyadd.Text = "";
                    }
                }


            }






            lblpono.Text = dt.Rows[0]["compcode"].ToString();
            if (dt.Rows[0]["mstdate"] != null)
            {

                lbldate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt.Rows[0]["mstdate"]);
            }
            else
            {
                lbldate.Text = "";
            }
            lblconsignee.Text = dt.Rows[0]["mstdepa"].ToString();
            lblattn.Text = dt.Rows[0]["acctname"].ToString();
            if (dt.Rows[0]["acctname"] != null)
            {
                lblcompany.Text = "For " + dt.Rows[0]["acctname"].ToString();
            }
            imglogo.Attributes.Add("src", "/office%20pro/CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_86d5effd-30fa-48d6-9a87-49b5ae9a616a.png");
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dtconsigneeinfo = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sp_GetAccountinfo", c.con);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acctname", dt.Rows[0]["mstdepa"]);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd2;
            da.Fill(dtconsigneeinfo);
            if (dtconsigneeinfo.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dtconsigneeinfo.Rows[0]["acctphon"] != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtconsigneeinfo.Rows[0]["acctphon"].ToString()))
                    {

                        lblphone.Text = dtconsigneeinfo.Rows[0]["acctphon"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblphone.Text = "";
                    }
                }
                if (dtconsigneeinfo.Rows[0]["acctaddr"] != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtconsigneeinfo.Rows[0]["acctaddr"].ToString()))
                    {

                        lbloffice.Text = dtconsigneeinfo.Rows[0]["acctaddr"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbloffice.Text = "";
                    }
                }


            }



        }

    }
```

Comment: it's not clear form your question kindly provide an example

Comment: in my grid there is only one item so see this sample report in which if there is only one row then this grid is displaying one blank row before footer so how can i do this

Comment: or can i do this by grid css without inserting row in grid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to so some thing when there is no row in your gridview then you can use EmptyDataTemplate of gridview.
When there is no data in the gridview this template is shown.
Since it is a template so you can design it according to your choice.
Here is an example of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx).

There too is an example of [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982237/asp-net-gridview-if-empty-show-message)
If you want to add something below you gridview you can use footer template.
There is a good example of footer template. http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1676759.

Since it is a template you can use html or server control inside it.

```
<FooterTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lbltotalquan" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td style='height:50px;'></td>
     <tr/>
 </table>
 </FooterTemplate>
```

This will create additional space below your footer. It can be done from code behind also.
Count the number of records in your datasouce and add table in footer.

Comment: You want to add something in footer. You can use footer template an example of it is here http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1676759

Comment: It is a template so you can use anything table tr td or div in it. And using it you can have some addition space below your grid view

Comment: As I told you you just add a table and set it's height I am going to edit my post for this.

Comment: at which column because i have only added template field for qty,rate and amount

Comment: should i also add this table in the other two template field also because the two fields qty and amount is becoming distorted and whether it is proper approach  if more items are added in grid or should i do it dynamicaly

Comment: it's not the proper approach. The approach should be add blank row if you have less number of rows. But there will be gap between your footer and the last row. If it is ok then you can go by this. Or not set the height of the footer in .cs (code) by counting number of rows in your datasource.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18960/discussion-between-iprogrammer-and-krshekhar)

Comment: Sorry that is not accessible from my organisation

Comment: the chat of stack overflow is not accessible in my organisation

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. How I can miss it. You can use style sheet for solving the problem.

 use **min-height**  property of CSS.

here is a link 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp